# android complex onDraw() method vs custom layout

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm new to android development and I want to create a custom chart view (I know there are some libs for that, but I want to make my one view). I want it to have a chart, axes and a chart name (a label). I see two options how to implement this.

1) Subclass a view and have a complex draw method. Something like this (possibly with helper classes to draw axis, labels and so on)

```
drawChart();
drawAxes();
drawLabels();
```

2) Create a `View` subclass for drawing a chart itself, a `View` subclass for horizontal axis, a `View` subclass for vertical axis, and a `Label`. Then create a `ViewGroup` subclass and implement a custom layout.

Which method is preferable ?

Answer (score 0):

My point is that you should use a custom layout, so you won't have to redraw a potentially complex chart and you could center on just gathering and managing the data.

Better for reuse too if you make your own library after finishing ;)